# DecimalFormat, как настроить отображение результата

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно вывести число с двумя знаками после запятой. Я использовал

```
text_mgn_rashod.setText(String.format("%.2f", _fuel_millisec).replace(",", "."));
```

и получал 0,56 к примеру. Но Андроид студио подсвечивал эту запись. Типа нужно по-другому.
Сейчас я решил использовать другую запись:

```
NumberFormat nf_2
nf_2 = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
text_mgn_rashod.setText(nf_2.format(_fuel_millisec));
```

И сейчас я получаю:

0 вместо 0.00.

0,2 вместо 0,20

Как мне при использовании NumberFormat получать текст в 3 символа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл решение

```
nf_2 = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```